# PopUntil target Route? routes = A,B,C,D if route on D popuntil B

Tags: flutter

This is how I generate my routes:

```
     switch (settings.name) {
      case '/':
        return CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (_) => SplashPage());
      case '/login':
        return CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoginPage());
      case '/home':
        return CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomePage());
      case '/catalogTree':
        return CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (_) => CatalogPageTree());
      case '/uploadImageCropper':
        return CupertinoPageRoute(
            builder: (_) =>
                UploadImageCropper(args: args != null ? args : null),
            fullscreenDialog: true);
      case '/uploadImageConfirm':
        return CupertinoPageRoute(
            builder: (_) =>
                UploadImageConfirm(args: args != null ? args : null),
            fullscreenDialog: true);
      case '/rentTree':
        return CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (_) => RentPageTree());
      case '/rentGallery':
        return CupertinoPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => RentImageGallery(args: args != null ? args : null));
      case '/cart':
        return CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (_) => CartPage());
     ...
```

In this case I am on B and I am pushing to C then to D with:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/uploadImageCropper', arguments: {'img': imagePath, 'baseContext': context}); // /uploadImageCropper is page C in this example

Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/uploadImageConfirm', arguments: {'img': imagePath, 'baseContext': context}); // /uploadImageConfirm is page D in this example

// and just in case people ask, I guess page A is /home
```

I tried:

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName("/catalogTree")); // /catalogTree is page B in this example
```

But it sends me into a black page. **I just want to go from page D to page B**

Navigator `pushReplacement` or `push` are not very efficient solutions as they either eliminate page A or duplicate routes.

Comment: You don't seem to have a 'Page1' on your route stack, hence the black page. It's a stack...so either just repeat pop until you get to where you want, or get the name of the page you want to pop to, right.

Comment: oops that was copy pasted from a site since I deleted the code on my script but I had the correct route name in my code. sorry about that, will update.